# Credit card start and end date selection

Tags: payments, creditcard

I'm implementing part of a payment process for a website and am just putting together the enter card details screen (card number, card holder's name, card start/expiry dates etc.).

I'm implementing the card start/expiry dates as month and year dropdowns but am not sure which years I should cover to ensure no one is unable to enter their details.

Does anyone have any information as to how long cards are issued for so as to determine the earliest possible start year and latest possible end year?

Also do I need to worry about any overlap of the current date. e.g. in December 2010 is it possible someone may have a valid card with a start date of January 2010?

Comment: FYI, the start date has no value of any kind. I wouldn't even bother capturing it.

Answer (score 2):

What I've done is simply include the current year + 20 as a dropdown selection. You can also simply allow the user to enter a numeric entry of 4 (or even 2) digits for the year and you're covered.

"[**Maximum Year in Expry Date of Credit Card**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500588/maximum-year-in-expry-date-of-credit-card)" on sister site [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) discusses this pretty well.

Comment: The second comment should have been an answer, on that question :)

Comment: I think I agree. ;)